# How can email be redirected from a domain host without mx records to google apps?

Tags: email, mx-record, redirection

My new domain host (Zymic) doesn't provide email and no mx records, either. Is there a way to direct the email coming in to my domain to google apps (or another domain) without mx records?

Answer (score 5):

You need MX records.  Period.  There may be tricks if they currently don't go to google apps to redirect your mail.  But it has to go somewhere to start with.

If your host really doesn't let you set MX records (which is unlikely) transfer your domain to someone who does.

Comment: It would appear that Zymic charge extra for MX records.

Comment: Looks like they are giving you the domain for free...so that kind of makes sense.  But you can find .com domains on sale for <US$3 with full dns service...so its not that expensive to get your own.

Comment: +1; Pay the extra, or transfer the domain/purchase another domain elsewhere